# Google datalab warning when plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-cloud-datalab

When I plot with datalab, I keep getting the same warning about font. It actually renders the plot fine, but I comes up every time. How can I get rid of it?

`df.plot();`

> /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1320:
>   UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling
>   back to DejaVu Sans   (prop.get_family(),
>   self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Answer (score 1):

VictorGGI solution did not work for me as the file always returned to its previous state (maybe reset on datalab restart ?). Anyway, a simpler fix to this issue would be to hide warnings with :

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the docker container where Datalab is running using the steps in [here](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/working-with-notebooks#using_git_from_the_command_line).

```
docker ps
docker exec -it <your-container-id> bash
```

Access the directory where the `font_manager.py` file is located:

```
cd /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/
```

Edit the `font_manager.py` file and comment out lines [1227,1228,1229](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/font_manager.py#L1227)

```
  #warnings.warn('findfont: Could not match %s. Returning %s.' %
  #                        (prop, self.defaultFont[fontext]),
  #                        UserWarning)
```

(if you cannot use vim/vi or whatever text editor you can make use of [gsutil command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#upload_an_object_into_your_bucket) and upload the file to a bucket, edit it and download it again)